# c# change button.text from another method

Tags: c#, function, properties

I am programming a little sudoku game. I have a 2d-Array and lots of buttons that display numbers. When I click on one of those buttons(*sudokuBoxClicked*) I get the x and y position of the button from its name. That works for now. At the end of the function, the function *changeNumberinSudoku* is opened. This function first changes the array-entry to the number I want on that button.text, then it shall change the button.text so that it is no longer *null* but has the value of the variable *changeNumber*

As I have 81 buttons in my sudoku, the program has no idea what button.text it should change. So it should change the text-property of the button that triggered the *sudokuBoxClicked*-function. My question now is basically:

**How do i get the object sender to the 2nd function, so that I may change its properties?**

To give you a better understanding of what I need, here is the important code:

```
    int changeNumber = 1;
    int[,] sudokuMap = new int[9,9];

    private void sudokuBoxClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string nameOfClickedBox = (sender as Button).Name;
        int xPositionOfClickedButton = Convert.ToInt32(nameOfClickedBox.Substring(7, 1));
        int yPositionOfClickedButton = Convert.ToInt32(nameOfClickedBox.Substring(9, 1));
        //The array-position of the clicked box, is contained in its name. 
        changeNumberinSudoku(xPositionOfClickedButton, yPositionOfClickedButton);
    }
    private void changeNumberinSudoku(int xPos, int yPos)
    {
        sudokuMap[xPos, yPos] = changeNumber;


    }
```

Thanks to all the nice people out there who would be able to help me.

-AlexanderLe

Comment: which 2nd function ? are you talking about "changeNumberinSudoku" function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the sender as an argument to the second function:

```
changeNumberinSudoku(xPositionOfClickedButton, yPositionOfClickedButton, (sender as Button));
```

And change your function signature:

```
private void changeNumberinSudoku(int xPos, int yPos, Button btn)
{
    sudokuMap[xPos, yPos] = changeNumber;

    btn.Text = ...
}
```

Comment: @Alexander Glad to help. If this answers your question, you can click the check mark to accept it.